# Trigger Send With Content Syndication via HTTPget

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, automation

We are building automated emails in ExactTarget (Salesforce Marketing Cloud) that pull the most recent blog post into an email via HTTPget. The problem is our blog post in the email is never updating. This strategy works fine when we do a regular email send, but when we put this in a triggered send definition the content area appears cached and never updates.

Below is the email syndication documentation.

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/content_syndication/

Any idea what I'm missing?

EDIT: 1/19/2015 @2:03pm -------

The working code is simple an HTTPget AMPscript call. See below:

```
  %%= BeginImpressionRegion("Name Of Impression Region") =%%

  %%[
      Set @taca = TreatAsContentArea("3200", HTTPGet("http://contenturl.com?queryparam=123", false, 0, @CallStatus)) 
  ]%%

  %%= EndImpressionRegion() =%%

/* Bunch of conditionals that will evalute if there is an error */

  %%=v(@taca)=%%%
```

Comment: Can you add some of the important code from the email so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a GUID() value at the end of the URL you're fetching.

```
%%[
Set @taca = TreatAsContentArea("3200", HTTPGet(concat("http://contenturl.com?queryparam=123&guid=",guid()), false, 0, @CallStatus)) 
]%%
%%=v(@taca)=%%
```

Comment: Great thanks. I should be able to do some testing in the next day or so and I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: It actually did not work. I appreciate the help though, sorry for not getting back.